# Moved database to new instance - permission issues

Tags: sql-server

I had to upgrade SQL server Express from 2017 to 2019. I have some tables that I backed up from the old instance and restored to the new instance. I then recreated the user I needed in the new instance with the same privileges. It seems I can login as that user but I cannot access the table.

If I try to edit that user's table privileges in "NewInstanceName -> Logins -> UserName" I get the message"

> Create failed for User 'toolLocation'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> User, group, or role 'toolLocation' already exists in the current
> database. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15023)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You're trying to `CREATE` an `USER` here that already exists. What was the SQL you ran here?

Comment: Remember: SQL Server separates the concepts of a login from a user. It's likely the initial restore already provided you with one of those items, but neglected the other.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Tool.

Comment: After restoring the database on the new instance and creating new logins, have you tried using [`ALTER USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql) to map the (old, unlinked) database users up to the logins?

Comment: I am woefully ignorant of managing users/permissions with sql commands. Is there a way to do this using SQL Server Management Tool or some other GUI?